# learning type of argument in function

Tags: haskell

How can I learn type of argument at function in Haskell ? In python, we have type ( ) function.

```
Ex:    
  in func; 

       if  type ( a ) == Int 
           do <something>
```

But, I don't know how I can manage that wish in Haskell ?

Comment: Haskell is strongly typed so you always know what type the parameters to functions are. Sometimes this is relaxed due to typeclasses, but in this latter case you always know what operations are permitted on the parameter even though you can't know its concrete type.

Comment: If you explain what you want to do, we can explain how to do it in Haskell.  Dynamic type tests are almost never the right way.

Comment: It might sound a little cult-like or restrictive that everyone is saying "you shouldn't need it," but 1) You really don't need it, and 2) A ton of expressive power is *gained* by the reason you aren't able to do what you want to here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If Something Is Not A List In Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463777/if-something-is-not-a-list-in-haskell)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need this since Haskell is statically typed and all types are known at compile time. In case of polymorphic functions like `length :: [a] -> Int` (Calculate the length of a list of elements of type `a`), there is no way to find out about the type of the argument, since you specified with the type that any argument type fits.

Comment: Note, however, that there may be different constructors of the same datatype, that should be processed differently. You can handle them with pattern matching.

Answer (score 4):

You have http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Typeable.html

However compared to dynamic languages it is very very rare that you need to use such means, and as beginner you shouldn't even try to use it, as you're almost certainly doing it wrong, even if you are sure that you need it. You should embrace Haskell's battle cry "Follow the type!" and  express your thoughts *using* the type system instead of trying to subvert it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do type-directed dispatch, then you probably want a typeclass.

```
data Bar = ...

class Foo a where
  foo :: a -> Bar

instance Foo Int where
  foo = ...

func :: Foo a => a -> ...
func x ... = ... foo x ...
```

Notice how the type signature demands that `x` is an instance of the `Foo` class. That means we can call `foo` on `x` and the type-directed dispatch will be done *for* us, in a type-safe way. If you write code that tries to call `foo` on something that is not an instance of `Foo`, then it will be a type error.

---

The reason you are not allowed to perform your own type-directed dispatch in Haskell is because that would break some important guarantees given to you by the type system. We would have to say goodbye to our [theorems for free](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/parametricity.html).